# Creating a row of hexagons using pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a row of hexagons using CSS, but I need there to be 7 in a single row and for some reason they've been cut off (apart from the middle hexagon) as show here:

[image]

I need them to look more like:
[image]

Here's the code I have so far:

```css
.hex-container {
  width:310px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative; 
}

.hex-container div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:120px;
  height:104px;
  margin:0 -13px;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.hex-container div::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, #f09800,#fad900);
}

.hex-container div:nth-child(1),
.hex-container div:nth-child(3),
.hex-container div:nth-child(4),
.hex-container div:nth-child(6) {
  margin-top:54px;
  margin-bottom:-54px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hex-container">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

This is modified from [this tutorial](http://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html) and with help from an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521596/applying-a-linear-background-colour-to-a-group-of-hexagons-in-css) I asked on Stack Overflow

Comment: For the shadow, you may use filter :   `filter:drop-shadow(1px 1px 2px #000)`  wrapping is also possible . example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VwapmLd .flex seems easier to manage and pseudo might be omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the negative margin bottom and use `vertical-align:top`

```css
.hex-container {
  width:310px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative; 
}

.hex-container div{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top; /* here */
  width:120px;
  height:104px;
  margin:0 -13px;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.hex-container div::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, #f09800,#fad900);
}

.hex-container div:nth-child(odd){
  margin-top:54px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hex-container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

And the full code with your 7 shapes:

```css
.hex-container {
  text-align:center;
  width:700px;
  position:relative; 
}

.hex-container div{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top; /* here */
  width:120px;
  height:104px;
  margin:0 -13px;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.hex-container div::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, #f09800,#fad900);
}

.hex-container div:nth-child(odd){
  margin-top:54px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hex-container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your absolutely positioned `:before` element has height of relatively positioned ancestor (.hex-container).

Set it's height on what you need (e.g. 200px) and you will see whole hexagons.